# Getting Android account manager from qt in c++

Tags: android, c++, qt, qandroidjniobject

Using this code:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QtAndroid::androidActivity();
QAndroidJniObject accountManager = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android.accounts.AccountManager","get","(Landroid/content/Context;)android.accounts.AccountManager;",activity.object());
qDebug() << accountManager.isValid();
```

I am trying to get an instance of  the android AccountManager in c++. Unfortantly the output of the line `qDebug() << accountManager.isValid();` outputs false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because of invalid method signature. You forget `L`. Also your object name is invalid. Look at some Qt examples. It's always like this

> jint max = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticMethod("java/lang/Math",
>   "max", "(II)I", a, b);

So valid string is:

```
QAndroidJniObject accountManager = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/accounts/AccountManager","get","(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/accounts/AccountManager;",activity.object());
```

Comment: Oh, good catch. But unfortunately there seem to be something else wrong, because after correcting I still get the same behavior :-(.

Comment: Yes! An additional error: change the "." in the returned class to "/". Than Your answer is complete.